SSIS Event Handler: Unable to Access OnError System Variables in ReadOnlyVariables
I am trying to set up an "OnError" event handler for my SSIS package, but I’ve run into a problem. All the system variables related to the "OnError" event are scoped under "OnError", which means none of my components can access them.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I created an "OnError" event handler directly under the Executables (specifically, for a Script Task).
However, the scope of the system variables (e.g., System::ErrorCode, System::ErrorDescription) remains under "OnError".
I’m unable to move these variables out of the "OnError" scope to make them accessible within my components.

Problem:
Even after setting up the event handler, I can’t access the "OnError" system variables in my Script Task or other components.
Question:
How can I correctly configure the OnError event handler to access its system variables in components? Am I missing a step or misconfiguring the scope?

Screenshot for Reference:


Your components will be able to access them as you create them in the on error scope. If you can't access them from your components, you've created them in the wrong place/scope; you're not creating the in the OnError Event handler.

@ThomA – I’ve created the "OnError" event handler at the package level under Event Handlers:
View of Event Handlers
Here’s the Package Explorer view for reference:
View of Package Explorer

Then you'll be able to access the system variables. Why do you believe you can't?

@ThomA – I can’t add the variables as "ReadOnlyVariables", nor can I access them anywhere else.
Available ReadOnlyVariables

I can see it fine. Did you enable "Show system variables" in the "Variable Grid Options" menu?

@ThomA Yes- However, i also need to enable "Show variables of all scopes" to even se it. If only "Show system variables" is enabled, i can't see it.

I can't replicate that problem I'm afraid.

@ThomA - Yeah, i found it why it didn't work. See my answer. Little bit embarrassing..

Wow, okay.
This is my first time working with event handlers, and I just realized my mistake.
I was trying to access the variables and everything in the Control Flow tab, not understanding that you need to add components directly to the Event Handler tab.
A little embarrassing, but perhaps someone in the future will make the same mistake and can learn from this!
Here’s what the correct setup looks like:


This is what I stated you might be doing in the first comment... "you've created them in the wrong place/scope; you're not creating the in the OnError Event handler."

@ThomA Yea... Sorry about that
